# create a program that says the minimum amount of contacts

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

Given a graph describing the relationships of the social network, create a program that tells the minimum amount of contacts to reach John.

**Input:**

The first line of the input indicates how many are the **n** vertices of the graph (2 ≤ n ≤ 100). The next n lines each represent the information of a vertex in the format: **id,A,v1,v2,⋯,vA**, where **id** is an integer identifying the vertex, **A** is the number of edges connected to this vertex, and each **vi ≠ id** is an integer identifying a vertex adjacent to **id**. The last line has two **ids**, separated by space, that represent you and John, respectively.

**Exit:**

Present the minimum amount of contacts needed to reach John, if possible, the message "**Forevis alonis...**" otherwise.

**Observation:**
Each network user is represented by a unique **id**. In the first example, John is already one of your contacts. In the second case, you have to go through users **2** and **3** to reach the idol. In the latter case, it is not possible to contact you...

[image]

My code for this problem so far has been this as I haven't been able to solve the problem. Code:

```
graph = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
  v, A, *neighbor = map(int,(input().split()))
  graph[v] = neighbor
I, John = map(int, input().split())

def shortest_way(origin, destination, path=[]):
  path.append(origin)
  if origin == destination:
    return path
  shorter = [] 
  for neighbors in graph[origin]:
    if neighbors not in path:
      outro_caminho = shortest_way(neighbors.destination.path[:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use one `list` as the current `path` and then once the destination is reached, to store save it in `paths` so that at the end you can compare all possible solutions and return the shortest one.

```py
def shortest_way(origin, destination, path, paths):
  if origin == destination:
    path += [destination]
    paths.append(path)
    return paths
  for neighbor in graph[origin]:
    if neighbor not in path:
      shortest_way(neighbor, destination, path+[origin], paths)
  return paths

paths = shortest_way(I, John, [], [])
if not paths:
  print("Forevis alonis...")
print("shortest path =", min([len(i) for i in paths]))
```