# find out if vertices are connected to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I can't solve this problem, any help will be good.

teacher Açaizeiro Bórus Djorus is responsible for the new big project in his city: an aqueduct to supply açaí in almost every home. As the piping is expensive, he asked for your help to minimize costs and guarantee the energy of the people! His task is to find the lowest possible expense on the piping to connect all the homes as a supplier. Each meter of pipe costs R$ 3.14.

**Input:**

The first input line indicates how many there are n households in the region (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). The next n lines each represent information from a vertex in the format: **id,d1,v1,d2,v2,⋯,dA,vA**, where **id** is an integer identifying the residence, **A** is the number of neighbors of **id**, and each **vi ≠ id** is an integer identifying a neighboring house, which is located at a distance of **di** meters from **id**.

**Exit:**

Present the total value of the piping needed to connect all the homes.

**Comments:**

Each network user is confirmed by a unique **id**, the todograph is undirected, connected and loopless. In the first example, all vertices are connected to each other, and the minimum pipe required is 13 meters (R$ 40.82) connecting the houses in the following sequence: **(3.1)** and **(1,2)** In the second example, the minimum pipe required is 190 meters (R$ 596.60) connecting the residences in the following sequence: **(3.1)**, **(1,5)**,**(5,4)**,**(4,2)** and **(2, 6)**.

[image]

this is my code so far:

```
vertex, edges = [], []
for _ in range(int(input())):
  v, A, *neighbors = input().split()
  vertex.append(int(v))
  for i in range(0, len(neighbors), 2):
    edges.append((int(neighbors[i]), vertex[-1], int(neighbors[i + 1])))

total = 0
edges.sort(reverse=True)
agm = {v: set() for v in vertex}
```

Comment: How do you know your code doesn't work? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question.

Comment: my code does not solve the problem...

Comment: how do you know it doesn't solve the problem? Edit the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create a program that says the minimum amount of contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72062146/create-a-program-that-says-the-minimum-amount-of-contacts)